# Java: Date Time Conversion

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have a date format like "SA25MAY"; I need to convert it into date time variable and then I want to add one day in that. And then I need to return the answer in same format. Please do some needful

```
try {
  String str_date = "SA25MAY";
  DateFormat formatter;
  Date date;
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddd-dd-MMM");
  date = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);
  System.out.println("Today is " + date);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

ERROR:

```
  java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "SA25MAY"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
at javadatatable.JavaDataTable.main(JavaDataTable.java:29)
```

Here I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I am getting input like "SA25MAY"(Saturday25MAY) here I don't know how to convert it into date time variable

Comment: Please provide the code snippet you just tried in your question.

Comment: @YasinJamesBond you already told that in your question. Follow the link of sp00m.

Comment: Yah I saw the link of -[sp00m]. It is really useful. But still I am struggling.

Comment: Yah I saw the link of: [sp00m](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1225328/sp00m). It is really useful. But still I am struggling. please do some needful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add one day if you know the year because of leap years (29th of February).

In case the year is the current year, the following solution should do the the job:

For "SA25MAY":

```
try {
    String str_date = "SA25MAY";

    // remove SA
    str_date = str_date.replaceFirst("..", "");

    // add current year
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    str_date = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + str_date;

    // parse date
    Date date;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddMMM");
    date = formatter.parse(str_date);
    System.out.println("Today is " + date);

    // add day
    c.setTime(date);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    // rebuild the old pattern with the new date
    SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEddMMM");
    String tomorrow = formatter2.format(c.getTime());
    tomorrow = tomorrow.toUpperCase();
    tomorrow = tomorrow.substring(0, 2) + tomorrow.substring(3);
    System.out.println("Tomorrow is " + tomorrow);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or for "SA-25-MAY":

```
try {
    String str_date = "SA-25-MAY";

    // remove SA
    str_date = str_date.replaceFirst("..-", "");

    // add current year
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    str_date = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + str_date;

    // parse date
    Date date;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MMM");
    date = formatter.parse(str_date);
    System.out.println("Today is " + date);

    // add day
    c.setTime(date);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    // rebuild the old pattern with the new date
    SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE-dd-MMM");
    String tomorrow = formatter2.format(c.getTime());
    tomorrow = tomorrow.toUpperCase();
    tomorrow = tomorrow.substring(0, 2) + tomorrow.substring(3);
    System.out.println("Tomorrow is " + tomorrow);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`ddd` can not match `SUN`. Use `EEE` instead if you want to match the day name in the week.

Comment: Thanks Is working fine. But here I need to give input as SUN for Sunday,MON for monday and so on. But I am getting input like SA for Saturday.. It a two letter. I tried to match SU to EE, throws error